# MySQL query where condition problem

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a working query as

```
   SELECT p.id, 
          p.name AS ProductName, 
          count(DISTINcT s.salesid) as Sales, 
          Count(DISTINCT l.linkid) as Links
     FROM products p
LEFT JOIN sales s ON p.id=s.productid
LEFT JOIN links l ON p.id=l.productid 
 GROUP BY p.id
```

Now, I need only those records where either sales is not equal to 0 or links is not equal to 0 or both are not equal to 0

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a HAVING clause

```
SELECT p.id, p.name AS ProductName, 
count(DISTINcT s.salesid) as Sales, Count(DISTINCT l.linkid) as Links
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN sales s ON p.id=s.productid
LEFT JOIN links l ON p.id=l.productid 
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING Sales > 0 OR Links > 0
```